# parsing relevent info from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying do make a distance monitor by reading the RSSI value from a device using Bluetooth modals on two Raspberry Pi. I've got everything working now I just have to write some python to get the RSSI value and preform calculations to find the distance.

I'm using the command:

```
rssi = subprocess.Popen('sudo hcitool cc [MAC adrecss of divice]' shell=True, stdoutput=subprocess.PIPE)
```

using `rssi.comunicate()`

```
('RSSI return value: -5\n', none)
```

is returned.

I'm looking for a way I can parse the returned RSSI value (in this case -5) and assign it to a variable.

Comment: What part of the parsing isn't working? Have you written any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a_variable = int(rssi.communicate()[0].split()[-1])`

should work fine